# Unable to call a function from a vector of callbacks, get `expected function, found `Box<std::ops::FnMut(T) + 'a>`

Tags: callback, rust

I'm trying to implement a callbacks system in Rust 1.11. I think I've got the system set up right to store the callbacks, but I'm having trouble actually calling them. Example code:

```
struct Container<'a, T> {
    callbacks: Vec<Box<FnMut(T) + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a, T: Copy + PartialEq> Container<'a, T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Container {
            callbacks: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add_callback<F: 'a + FnMut(T)>(&mut self, callback: F) -> usize {
        let cb_id = self.callbacks.len();
        self.callbacks.push(Box::new(callback));
        cb_id
    }

    fn call_by_id(&self, cb_id: usize, value: T) {
        // This doesn't work and I don't know why:
        self.callbacks[cb_id](value);

        // It still doesn't work (same error) when I try to dereference the Box
        // *self.callbacks[cb_id](value);

        // It's not a dereferencing scoping issue, either
        // *(self.callbacks[cb_id])(value);
    }

}

fn main() {
    let mut list = Vec::new();

    {
        let mut container = Container::new();
        let append = container.add_callback(|v| list.push(v));

        container.call_by_id(append, 3);
        container.call_by_id(append, 4);
    }

    println!("List contains: {:?}", list);
    // Expect "List contains: [3, 4]", but it doesn't compile
}
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=268fc63db90a15bdfe1a0b6a87f9c6d7&version=stable&backtrace=0))

This gives the following error:

```
error: expected function, found `Box<std::ops::FnMut(T) + 'a>`
  --> <anon>:20:9
   |>
20 |>         self.callbacks[cb_id](value);
   |>         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

This is unusually unhelpful, for Rust; I'm having real trouble finding other instances of this error via Google or searching here.

The `Box` docs claim there's a generic `impl<T> Deref for Box<T> where T: ?Sized`, and the `Sized` docs say that the syntax `?Sized` is used to *remove* the requirement for the `Sized` trait. I understand this to mean, together, that `Box` implements `Deref` for every `T`, sized or not, so it should be in play here.

If that's the case, I don't understand *at all* why I can't just call the `Box` containing the callback, or (worst case) dereference `self.callbacks[cb_id]` to get access to the callable. My best guess at the moment is that it has something to do with the lifetimes in play, but if so, I just have no idea how to adjust them to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a smaller reproduction:

```
fn main() {
    let a: Vec<Box<FnMut()>> = vec![Box::new(|| println!("called"))];
    a[0]();
}
```

---

Let's break it down and watch the types and errors:

```
fn call_by_id(&self, cb_id: usize, value: T) {
    let () = self.callbacks[cb_id];
}
```

This shows that the type is `Box<std::ops::FnMut(T)>`. So far, so good. Store that in a variable and proceed:

```
fn call_by_id(&self, cb_id: usize, value: T) {
    let x = self.callbacks[cb_id];
    x(value);
}
```

Ah, right: `` error: cannot borrow immutable `Box` content `*x` as mutable ``...

```
fn call_by_id(&self, cb_id: usize, value: T) {
    let mut x = self.callbacks[cb_id];
    x(value);
}
```

Oops: `error: cannot move out of indexed content`...

```
fn call_by_id(&self, cb_id: usize, value: T) {
    let mut x = &mut self.callbacks[cb_id];
    x(value);
}
```

Ah ha: `` error: cannot borrow immutable field `self.callbacks` as mutable ``...

```
fn call_by_id(&mut self, cb_id: usize, value: T) {
    let mut x = &mut self.callbacks[cb_id];
    x(value);
}
```

**It compiles!** I'd probably leave it here (with a better name for `x`), but let's see if we can get it back to one line. Directly substitute:

```
fn call_by_id(&mut self, cb_id: usize, value: T) {
    (&mut self.callbacks[cb_id])(value);
}
```

Nope, back to `` error: expected function, found `&mut Box<std::ops::FnMut(T) + 'a>` `` Maybe a dereference instead:

```
fn call_by_id(&mut self, cb_id: usize, value: T) {
    (*self.callbacks[cb_id])(value);
}
```

Nope, `error: cannot borrow immutable`Box`content as mutable`. Being more specific about mutability:

```
fn call_by_id(&mut self, cb_id: usize, value: T) {
    (*&mut self.callbacks[cb_id])(value);
}
```

**This works**, but I'm not sure it's elegant.

---

In summary, the problem is that the variable for the callback is not mutable. This was caused by two things:

1. The binding of the vector of callbacks was not mutable (via `&self`).
2. The dereferencing of the callback *seemingly* doesn't understand the mutability requirements unless you are explicit. I'm not 100% sure why this is.

---

Note that in your commented code:

```
*self.callbacks[cb_id](value);
*(self.callbacks[cb_id])(value);
```

I'm pretty sure these are the same; `*`'s precedence will bind it to the result of the whole value. I think you meant:

```
(*self.callbacks[cb_id])(value);
```

Comment: Thanks! So all `FnMut` bindings must be mutable, then? I had thought their mutability referred only to their enclosed context. I guess that doesn't make sense, though; if they're a trait object which contains that context, then of course they have to be modifiable. It would be great if the error message explained that better; I really didn't understand what was going on.